# Scheme: Pascal's Triangle

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write a program that takes in a row and column number (both starting at 1) and gives back the value of Pascal's triangle at that row and column number.  Here's my attempt:

```
(define (pascal row column)
    ;;;if column is 1 or row == column, 1
    (if (or (= column 1)(= row column))
    1
    ;;;else (pascal row-1 column-1) + (pascal row-1 column+1)
    (+ (pascal (- row 1) (- column 1)) (pascal (- row 1) (+ column 1)))))
```

When I try calling

```
(pascal 3 2)
```

I get:

```
Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two elements that combine for position (row, column) are *not* (row-1,column-1) and (row-1, column+1).  (Try drawing a picture.)

Comment: Ah, it's (row, column) = (row - 1, column - 1) + (row - 1, column)!